# Advice on exception handling

Tags: python, exception

I would like to know if it is possible to capture exceptions into a list (store the errors), continue through a `for item in list` until all items have been iterated, then sort the errors and print the unique ones?

Hope this makes sense. Here is a simple example of a function to try to illustrate what I mean:

```
def function1(list1, list2)
    for item in list1:
        for item in list2:
            try:
                do stuff here #iterates both lists
            except:
                capture exception append to list
                errors = sort(exceptions)
    print unique exceptions
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "unique ones" when printing exceptions?

Answer (score -2):

Its easy to collect and not easy to filter

```
class SetForFilter(set):
     def add(self,x):
         if x in self:
             return False
         else:
             super(SetForFilter,self).add(x)
             return True


def function1(list1, list2):
    errors = []
    for item in list1:
        for item in list2:
            try:
                do stuff here #iterates both lists
            except Exception as e:
                errors.append(e)

    types = SetForTFilter()
    unique = filter( lambda x: types.add(type(x)), errors)
    for e in unique: print repr(e)
```

First create list for storing errors.
All Exceptions in python should be based on built-in `Exception` class, so `except Exception` mean capturing all exceptions. `as e` means that Exception will be stored in `e` variable. Appending e to errors i collect all of them.

All Exceptions are unique. Maybe you want capture unique exception types?

`types = SetForFilter()` is set (accepts only unique objects) returns True if add, False if not.

Comment: @wim Sorry could you explain why eri was given -1, i dont know what you mean by "using list comp for side effects?

Comment: @wim replaced [] to filter, and what do mean?

Comment: @eri Sorry could you please explain your answer, its all well and good giving an answer thank you, but i would like to understand the answer too

Comment: @iNoob added text... i only realize your code sample

Comment: -1 `set.add()` doesn't return anything, so using it in a conditional for the side-effect of calling it isn't considered a good practice by many, regardless of whether it's in a list comp, lambda, or anywhere else. So showing code that does so isn't good advice.

Comment: @eri thank you for your advice (albeit frowned upon). mertineau thank you for pointing out the bad advice. I have thought of a work around that works for me. I would like advice on its efficiency and consideration of its use around best practice. Is it frowned upon for me to post the code in the comments? If so shall i make a new question even tho it is related to this one?

Comment: @iNoob i removed frowned part, replacing more complex one. +1 if my advice usefull or i will remove "useless" answer respecting commentators reputation.

Comment: @eri You seem to be suffering from a case of one-lineritis.  Why not just use `seen = set()` and then write a `for` loop, checking if already in seen and adding otherwise.  Clear, obvious, readable.

Comment: @eri: No, not really -- because you don't seem to understand that a `set` is all that's needed, since you can't add an element to one more than once there's no need to check and add if not present already. Afterwards it can be turned into a list, sorted, and printed as desired.

Comment: @martineau he is adding the exception instances (which are all unique) to a collection if the *type* is unique.

Comment: @wim 4AM at my clock.. at this time obvious is not so obvious =) +1 for obvious `for loop`

Comment: @wim: If `errors` was a `set`, the exception handler could unconditionally do an `errors.add(type(e))`.

Comment: @martineau we need to print  represntation of Exception instances, not types